# What's the use of <element contentEditable="true"> in html?

Tags: html, contenteditable

It seems it allows you to edit the content of an element, but what is actually happening? What's the use of this property?

EDIT: see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is usually used for rich text input. While regular form elements like `<input type="text"/>` don't provide real rich text editing options, elements with `contentEditable` set to `true` can.
Most rich text editors (e.g. FCK Editor) available for the web are built using an `<iframe/>` with `contentEditable` set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`contentEditable=true` for elements make them editable. You can write/edit text in those elements as if they are a textarea or a text field.