# Get a specific number of results from an XmlDocument XPath query

Tags: asp.net, xpath, xmldocument

I'm querying a Twitter RSS feed and supplying the results into a Repeater for display. I'd like to only get the first 5 results of the XPath query. Is there a way to do that in the XPath syntax or do I have to loop over the resulting `XmlNodeList` to pull out the first 5?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(rssPath);
doc.Load(reader);

XmlNodeList items = doc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");

rptTwitter.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptTwitter_ItemDataBound);
rptTwitter.DataSource = items;
rptTwitter.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this XPath query instead:

```
(/rss/channel/item)[position() <= 5]
```

It returns only the first five matching items. The parentheses are important, as without them the `[position() <= 5]` part applies to the `item` element's position in its parent rather than its position in the result node set.

Comment: This is exactly what I need in my current situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to continue using xpath then you should look at the position() method in xpath. Using a predicate something like this...

```
[position() < 6]
```

... should result limit the results to only the first 5 items. Welbog's answer is your best reference here (+1 to Welbog).

**However**, if you're able to use .NET 3.5 then I would recommend you look at my answer here...

[What is the coolest thing you can do in <10 lines of simple code? Help me inspire beginners!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811074/what-is-the-coolest-thing-you-can-do-in-10-lines-of-simple-code-help-me-inspir/811236#811236)

... and take a look at the syndication APIs that make dealing with RSS feeds much easier. Then, if you only want 5 items, use the LINQ method Take on the collection to take a specific number of items.

This will allow you to express yourself better and not have to worry about the structure of the feed, namespaces etc.

I realise this isn't directly answering your question but as many people don't know about these new APIs in .NET I thought I'd mention them here.

So, your code to get just 5 items would be something like this...

```
var xmlr = XmlReader.Create("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.rss")
var first5Items = SyndicationFeed
                    .Load(xmlr)
                    .GetRss20Formatter()
                    .Feed
                    .Items
                    .Take(5);
```

Comment: Martin, thanks! This is a great alternative and I think I'll be using this more often. I'm not sure if my client's server is 3.5 so I'm staying away from LINQ right now but if I find out they have it, I'll use this. I just tried it locally and it works like a charm. I love having the actual properties for the RSS nodes.