# I need some help importing an RSS feed from Wordpress

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to import the last 5 posts from a Wordpress RSS feed and show them on my site.

I was using this, but it grabs the whole feed.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dataNews" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlSource" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="<%# XPath("link") %>"><%# XPath("title") %></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlSource" runat="server" DataFile="http://myblog.com/feed" XPath="rss/channel/item" EnableCaching="true" />
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath expressions to help you with this as documented here: [Get a specific number of results from an XmlDocument XPath query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827361/get-a-specific-number-of-results-from-an-xmldocument-xpath-query). The following should work.

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlSource" runat="server" DataFile="http://myblog.com/feed" XPath="rss/channel/item[position()<6]" EnableCaching="true" />
```

Comment: This works. So thanks for that! But if I blog feed is down, it will error out my whole front page. Should I write this all in the code behind or is there some options to do with my code?