# Get score for an url on Reddit, using jQuery getJSON

Tags: jquery, getjson, reddit

I am trying to get the score for a certain URL from reddit. To add a "share with reddit (count)" link:

```
function redditCounter(url) {
  // Get number of counts from reddit JSON api
  // $.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url='+url+'',
  $.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url=http://stackoverflow.com/q/811074/1288',
    function(data) {
      count = 0;
      if (data.children.count() > 0) {
        first_child = data.children[0];
        alert(first_child.score);
      }
    });
}
```

When you call the url with curl, or your browser, the result is like described in [Reddits API documentation](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API%3A-info.json). There is a children array and that contains a score with a number.

The `$.getJSON`, however, returns an empty answer, seen when stepping over it in firebug.

Is this a protection method by reddit maybe? Or am I using getJSON wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should actually be expecting a JSONP response, in which case I'm fairly certain you should append `&callback=?` to your URL.

EDIT: Just a note for anyone that stumbles across this question in the future: jQuery's `getJSON()` will fail silently if it encounters a malformed JSON object or, as in this case, receives a JSON object from another domain without the JSONP padding. However, some browsers (e.g: Google Chrome) may throw a MIME type warning that serves pretty well as an indicator that there's something wrong with the JSON object you're getting.