# Sample Program in Python

Tags: python

where do I find sample program of python ? I've got a book about Python " Hands-On Python
A Tutorial Introduction for Beginners Python 3.1 Version ", and it explains about there are a lot of sample program which can be used to practice, like : madlib.py, formatBraces.py, face.py, etc. But, I don't find them in Python's directory like the book said. I'm using Python 3.3, or is the problem because the author using Python 3.1 ? But, I don't think so. Does anyone here got the same problem ?

Comment: Those are not examples from the Python distribution itself, they are specific to that book. In any case, some of them seem to be [at this address](http://cs.luc.edu/anh/python/hands-on/examples.zip).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best ways to teach a beginner to program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088/best-ways-to-teach-a-beginner-to-program)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not examples from the Python distribution itself, they are specific to that book. In any case, some of them seem to be [at this address](http://cs.luc.edu/anh/python/hands-on/examples.zip).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm entirely answering your question but...there are many good websites where you can find sample code and how to do different things...i use these a lot...

http://docs.python.org/2/library/
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/lang/pytut27/web/index.html

These should give you the answers to what you're looking for :) sorry if i didnt answer your question properly

Comment: Never mind, Paulo Almeida gives the correct answer, but your answer is acceptable, happy programming.