# Python programming without downloading libraries

Tags: python

recently i learned python and its syntax and i started to write some little programs.Today i wanted to do something more complex and after some research i found out that i needed to download and import some libraries.I'd like to know how these libraries are written,for example i red the pyhook source but i didn't understand how it takes the input from keyboard and mouse.I need only a starting point to learn because i want to do things on my own in order to understand better how everything works.

Edit:
i know the language,what i need is a starting point to learn how to more complex things like controlling hardware and stuff like that without downloading libraries made by other members of Python community

Comment: Focusing on how it works is for when you've become better at knowing how to use it first. [Here's](http://better-dpt-roll.github.io/) a nice way to start using any language - pick some exercises from here and run with them

Comment: Thank you for the tip,maybe i need to slow down but i'm a bit impatient because i like IT and everything about it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best ways to teach a beginner to program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088/best-ways-to-teach-a-beginner-to-program)

Comment: It's a bit different because i know the language,what i need is a starting point to learn how to more complex things like controlling hardware and stuff like that without downloading libraries made by other members of Python community

Comment: Not a lot you can do without libraries, since most of Python's (more than basic) functionality is through them. Why are you against libraries? Also, what do you mean by control hardware? Python is a high-end language, it doesn't usually directly interact with hardware

Comment: I'm not against libraries,i want to know how people wrote them,i mean,there are libs written because before people couldn't do some things and i want to do the same thing to understand what happens when i use other libs.It's like learning a theorem at school,you can learn only the definition but to understand better you need the demonstration.I used the wrong word,i meant peripherals like keyboard,for example pyhook interacts with the keyboard and records the pressed keys

Comment: The thing about python is it's open source.  You can actually see the source code for the library that you're interested in.  Download it, and pore over the code.

Comment: I'd hold off on writing new libraries and looking deeply into existing ones simply because most of it wouldn't make much sense at first. A good starting point would be to write something you want to write, be it very basic or slightly complex, and learn to use the language as you go. When you're more efficient in it you could take segments in your code that you think other people can use, package them together and publish as a library